# is there a unified management console for Ubuntu 12?

Tags: 12.04, server, configuration, gui

is there something similar to the management console in Windows for example

1. GUI based Device Manager
2. In windows server there is a server management console through which we can manage all system services, installed web server etc.

would appreciate pointing me in the right direction

Comment: There are some attempts at GUI device discovery/settings, but not supporting configuration.  Are you already familiar with **Ubuntu Tweak**, which also supports extensions? (Note: *I have an early-stage project, with similar objectives to your wish-list.*)

Comment: Would you also want this to run remotely, with an Ubuntu-based GUI client supporting/maintaining multiple server/hosts?

Comment: just to be able to use it locally to manage the local machine is great, i wish you best of luck in your project and will look up Ubuntu tweak to see what can it do.

Comment: There are Web-GUI based options, including a commercial offering (with some limited free capabilities) from **Canonical** (the Ubuntu parent co.).  *Altough, this is not what you asked for ..*

Comment: david, whats the name of the product u r talking about?

Comment: **Landscape** is Canonical's web-based offering.  Otherwise, restate your question ..